# Why UITableVIew Display Data Incorrectly After Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource

My code is very simple. I have a fixed list of string to be displayed on UITableView, with custom UITableViewCell, which only has a UILabel on it.

My problem is that altho the data was displayed correctly initially, it displayed incorrectly after scrolling.

Here are more details. DataSource is a list `[(String, something_else)]`

The content of the list is

```
[("aaaaaa", something),
("bbbbbb", something),
("cccccc", something),
   ...
("rrrrrr", something)]
```

The screen is big enough to display "aaaa" to "mmmm". When I scroll down, the next visible line should be "nnnn", but it was "rrrr", after "rrrr" was "aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", then I scroll up, it gave me "eeee", "cccc", "rrrr". It was slightly different every time I restarted the simulator.

As you can see in the code below, I added `print(cell.note)` every time `cell` was dequeued and `cell.note` was set, but the printed messages in console indicate cells were set to the correct note. Yes, it looked correct. After "mmm", it was n,o,p,q,r, then I scroll up, it was f,e,d,c,b,a, it looked correct.

I don't understand why and I don't know how to solve it. Googling didn't give anything so I wanna try finding help here. Thank you for reading this.

Below are my code. Very simple implementation of dataSource and delegate

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data.count;
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview?.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NoteNodeCell") as! NoteNodeCell
        cell.note = data[indexPath.row].0        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 64
    }
}
```

NoteNodeCell is a custom UITableViewCell. I basically only added a UILabel in it.

```
class NoteNodeCell: UITableViewCell {
    var note: String {
        get { cellView.note }
        set { cellView.note = newValue }}
    
    var cellView:CellView = CellView()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        if cellView.superview != contentView {
            contentView.addSubview(cellView)
        }
        
        cellView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cellView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        note = ""
    }
}


class CellView: UIView {
    var note = "" { didSet { print(note) }}
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let label = UILabel(frame: bounds)
        label.text = "  " + note
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 18)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.backgroundColor = .gray
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        label.layer.masksToBounds = true
        UIColor.clear.setFill()
        addSubview(label)

    }
}
```

Thank you again for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your CellView class

```
class CellView: UIView {
let label = UILabel()
var note = "" { 
    didSet { 
        print(note) 
        self.label.text = "  " + note // this
    }
}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupSubviews()
}

private func setupSubviews() {
    label.text = "  " + note
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 18)
    label.textColor = .white
    label.backgroundColor = .gray
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    label.layer.masksToBounds = true
    addSubview(label)
}
```

}

and your UITableViewCell would need this

```
let cellView = CellView(frame: .zero)
```

Let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: But I have a follow-up question. I thought if I added cell.setNeedsDisplay, it would also solve the problem, but it didn't work. Your solution worked. That means i don't understand what's wrong. Can you help explain?

Comment: @Goatt setNeedsDisplay() notifies the system that your view needs to be redrawn. Assuming you properly updated the note variable before calling setNeedsDisplay, I don't see why it wouldn't work. I haven't seen the code where you were doing that though, so it's hard for me to say any more than that. I think it's bad practice to repeatedly redeclare and define a new label for no reason inside the draw function like that. You don't need to redo everything to just change the text of the label. That's why I wrote mine the way I did. I'm glad it helped!